# What are automatable rheostats called?

Tags: potentiometer, automation

I need to find something like this but that is automatable, over I2C or GPIB or something.

Is there a name for this? I am having problems finding something. Worst case I can buy this and hook up a motor to it, but I imagine a cheap packaged solution already exists, I just don't know the name for it.

Looking for these specs:
7Vrms (so ~20W at the low end of 3ohm, <1W above 50ohm)
3ohm-100ohm in ~20 log spaced steps
Automatable

A decade box could also work if it were automatable. They seem to be very expensive ($6k) for both automatable and specced for power.

The specific application is for loading a sigma delta (Class D) op amp (an audio amplifier). The output is differential and switching, a 1kHz AC sine wave is the resulting waveform after low pass filtering. A constant DC current sink will not fit the bill unfortunately. Open to other solutions though!

[image: Rheostat 25W]

Comment: Do you need the analog control knob aspect? If not, you're looking for a simple digital potentiometer.

Comment: This question will be tough to answer. What are your real requirements? 3-100Ohm @ what wattage? When you request a value, what tolerance do you have for accuracy?

Comment: @pgvoorhees 3-100ohm at 7Vrms, so at the low end, that will be about 20W for the 3ohm case, 50+ ohms will only require <1W

Comment: @SwimBikeRun Honestly, unless you want to build some kind of wiper driver, I think you might be in for something like a class-AB amplifier.

Comment: You can build a resistor network and use a CMOS multiplexer to select the resistor you want.

Comment: @Swim: Why don't you explain the application? You may be fixed on a poor solution to a problem which has better answers.

Comment: Have you calculated the 20 log resistance values? If so, can you post them in your question?

Comment: @transistor, It's intended to be as a load for a switching sigma delta amplifier. Cannot use an automatable current sink for that reason (the switching). Needs to be a resistor.

Comment: Is the load connected to ground?

Comment: @transistor No it's a differential output. Did you have an idea if it's connected to ground? I'm at a loss for what to do. I think I will try to build a stepper motor rig that will control this potentiometer.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of an R-2R divider. See the [Logrithmic Ladder](http://www.eijndhoven.net/jos/switchr/index.html) but it is single-ended and needs the ground reference. I'm still at a loss to understand what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @transistor I'm trying to scale up a process where I need to run a power vs load test and capture the sweep data. The load is connected to a differential class D audio amplifier. Before I did it by hand, just connecting different loads and making sure the loads were rated for the power. I need to do it 500 times now, so the load switching by hand isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The part you are describing is simply called a "motorized rheostat". It's not a common component, but does exist as a special-purpose item for certain industrial applications.

Control of motorized rheostats tends be pretty crude. Don't expect digital inputs; what you get is likely to be more along the lines of a pair of limit switches.

Answer (score 0):

Rheostat means current controller.   If you want to control a HIGH
current, for a DC motor, the usual approach is a PWM (pulse-width modulation)
drive style of motor controller.   That relies on the motor to be inductive,
and/or have a flywheel characteristic.   Rheostats for lighting AKA
dimmer circuits (often AC phase control) are 
very different.   For power-handling efficiency, big power resistor controls
are rare nowadays, but they traditionally did both those tasks.

A DC motor speed control using I2C, like this
http://www.ti.com/product/DRV2604/datasheet
comes close (it only likes 5.5V input, though).